# org-mode pandoc export to docx and open

Tags: org-export

When I export my documents to pdf (as pdf file and open `C-c l o`) I get pdf file opened in separate application.

For pandoc export to docx I do the 'same' (to docx and open `C-c p x`) but result file is opened in emacs itself with binary data and all the inner stuff of that file.

How can I tell emacs to open it in msword instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, before asking a question I was searching for about 20 min with no luck.

Right after it was posted I've found an answer:

```
;; open docx files in default application (ie msword)
(setq org-file-apps
      '(("\\.docx\\'" . default)
        ("\\.mm\\'" . default)
        ("\\.x?html?\\'" . default)
        ("\\.pdf\\'" . default)
        (auto-mode . emacs)))
```